# Offensive Insect attacks (turn back Entomophobs)

Tags: combat, insects

I got this character that has micro-robots in his nervous system that come together and send signals to insects with the micro-robots in them. These effectively give him mind control over these insects.

As of the beginning of the story the amount of insects is exactly 100,000,000 cockroaches, termites, common wasps, honey bees, house flies, fire ants, Giant Wetas, common locusts, hornets, bed bugs, cicadas, mosquitoes, lice, and fleas.

What (offensive) attacks to a person in a battle situation that will last for about 30 min to 4 hours could he do with this army of insects at his disposal?

If you need an idea of what I'm exactly talking about look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2V6Uy1X1OXU).

Comment: I would say, you would have insects fly onto the target and just chew/sting them up. With the numbers, it would be impossibly hard to fight off that many insects without suffering heavily. If you mean to apply a force, by having the insects group up, I'm not sure how plausible that is and how it would affect the flying dynamics of that many insects.

Comment: *Nanobots as mind control vector* have a long and "glorious" tradition (though mostly in the erotic fiction realm).

Comment: How do you get all those bugs to where you need them when you need them?  (Logistics, logistics, logistics...)

Comment: @RonJohn well it depends, not all the bugs go with him, some hide in his clothing, houseflies, bedbugs, lice, and fleas, and some follow and hide in the buildings, cockroaches are really fast, proportionally, or just ride in the car with him, most remain at his house reproducing to make bigger armies and sustaining thee colonies, if they have them.

Comment: not sure I really understand 'what(offensive) attacks to a person in a battle situation that will last for about 30 min to 4 hrs could he do with this army of inverts at his disposal?', you want the insect attack to last .5-4 hours? I feel like for any fight unless you have a one-hit lethal it's unpredictable how long it will take for consecutive minor damages to add up

Comment: @BKlassen Its more like i don't want the battle to last anymore than 4 hours, i prefer for it to be doable in 30 min, but up to 4 hours is okay

Comment: @Amoeba can you tell us what his attackers have/powers is he fighting hand to hand combat, or is the guys hes fighting have firearms? and the biggest is do they have powers as well, if it a guy that is covered in fire your insects are not going to do much. and dose the insect controller use the insects as canon fodder or doe he care about them (changes tactics a lot)

Comment: @CreedArcon Cyborgs with guns, tasers, speed, strength, and grappling hooks/ governments/ mutants, I'm still developing the villains so those are some of the general ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had direct command of an insect swarm with the intent to use them to cause harm I would think the most effective thing to do would be to target soft spots on the face, sting/bite around the eyes, enter the ears and nose and sting/bite from the inside, if there is the opportunity enter the mouth and do the same there. From the inside of the ears, nose and mouth your insects are nearly completely protected while they inflict their damage. Also if you were able to get enough insects into the mouth or nose you might be able to cause asphyxiation just having them pile up

Answer (score 1):

Your wasps and hornets, neither of them lose their stingers after stinging, so if you can direct what parts of the body they sting, you can do some serious damage. Hornet stings are the worst (they can actually leave scars - my dad has one on his ear). Also they are bugs. They're small and hard to hit, so they are the offensive ones, the rest can be used as shrouds to blind opponents.

Comment: also why is the combat time so spesific?

Comment: because I didn't want people answering things that would take too long for the quick, action packed battles i usually put in my stories